# Programmatically create membership database on SQL Server CE with Universal Providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, sql-server-ce, membership-provider

I need to programmatically create a standard membership database on a SQL Server CE4 server. I am using the asp.net universal providers to provide membership as described here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx

I tried using the `System.Web.Management SqlServices.Install()` as follows:

```
SqlServices.Install("local.sdf", SqlFeatures.Membership, connectionString.ConnectionString);
```

But it always throws an error saying it can't connect to the SQL Server database.

I suspect `SqlServices.Install()` may not support connection to SQL Server CE but I am curious if somebody else found a workaround. This is a MVC3 application and I'm trying to automate building an empty database prior to fresh deployment of the app.

Comment: The provider will create the database file for you...

Answer (score 0):

ErikEJ is correct. However in order for the membership provider to generate the .sdf (SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database) you'll need to supply the appropriate connectionString in your web.config as outlined in the ***[Hanselman post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)***.

Further, I found that using the approach you've already began and describe in your initial post Jon Galloway has a great SimpleMembership walkthrough that does almost identically what you're doing only instead of using the MembershipProvider it uses SimpleMembership, I've found that the material to be quite interchangeable.

I'm ***[living proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259581/mvc4-membership-sql-server-compact-4-0-exception-unable-to-find-the-reque/16266927#16266927)***, rock on!