# MVC4 - Membership - SQL Server Compact 4.0 - Exception: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-5

The ***[InitializeDatabaseConnection Method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569134%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)*** says we can use the MVC 4 "Internet" template's generated membership functionality with SQLCE (SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database).

I've used this template many times before and have never had a problem when I didn't fiddle with anything and simply used the localDb (the default) that is generated by the Entity Framework the first time we register a user.

My requirement is to get the membership tables that are by default generated into 2012 localDb database instead to generate into a SQLCE database. However, I'm getting the following:

***Exception: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.***

To do this we simply:

1. Open Visual Studio (express works fine).
2. Generate a new ***MVC4 --> Internet*** (with account) project.
3. Add a SQLCE database to the `~/App_Data/` folder (right-click the folder and select Add --> SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database).
4. Add table then a record to the table.
5. Right-click the ***Models*** folder and select *Add --> ADO.NET Entity Data Model*
6. Open the (root) web.config and copy the name of the 'connectionstring'(`<add name="ceEntities"`)
7. Locate the following line of code in the `~/Filters/InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` class: `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ceEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);`
8. F5 to compile/run/debug the project
9. Once the home/index page loads click the "Register" link in the upper right hand corner
10. Enter a username and password to register and click 'Ok.'

Up to this point the code compiles and runs fine however when the following line of code is run in the `~/Filters/InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` class:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ceEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

This exception is caught:
***Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.***

Which is apparently fixed when we **add this code to the web.config**:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

And when we run it again the following exception is caught:

***Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.***

Comment: Marc S, please stop editing my posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you to Scott Hanselman and whoever made him aware of the Membership Provider with SQLCE protocol as in his ***[Introducing System.Web.Providers - ASP.NET Universal Providers for Session, Membership, Roles and User Profile on SQL Compact and SQL Azure blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)*** Scott outlines the steps to implement the ASP.NET Universal Providers. This helped me as he outlined the proper connection string outline for SQLCE:

```
<connectionstrings>
   <add name="Sql_CE" 
        connectionstring="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyWebSite.sdf;" 
        providername="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0">
   </add>
</connectionstrings>
```

So I updated my connectionstring to:

```
<connectionstrings>
   <add name="defaultconnection" 
        connectionstring="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ce.sdf;" 
        providername="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0">
   </add>
</connectionstrings>
```

Then updated `connectionStringName` the `~/Filters/InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` class back to:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("defaultconnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

The application compiled without an error or exception so I ran the application then Registered a user and in that process the applicable SimpleMembership tables were generated into my "ce.sdf" (SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database).

I am now able to utilize the SimpleMembership default's at their fullest!

p.s., For brevity I'm going to now edit my initial post/question to omit the stacktraces, leaving only the exceptions.

Comment: Thank you... wait can't just say thank you... FYI; I needed to have `connectionString` and `providerName` (pascalCase) in my case

Answer (score 0):

Random suggestion but it may need to be added.as a namespace to the web.config file or as a package in the packages file, I could be wrong

Comment: Specifically what namespace are you suggesting be added to the web.config?